# Differentiability of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = u(x, y) + i v(x, y)$ be a complex function which is differentiable at $z_0 = x_0 + i y_0$. Can we say that the component functions $u$ and $v$ are also differentiable at $(x_0, y_0)$?

Comment: What do you mean by differentiable? As functions $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$, no, as functions $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, yes.

Comment: Differentiability of $f(z)$ implies the existence of partial derivatives of $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ and $y.$ Also $f(z)$ is continuous. Would that make answer?

Comment: @ copper.hat: As function $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
The function $f:D\subset \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ defined on the open set $D$ is complex differentiable at $z_0\in D$, if there exists a complex number $d$ such that:

$\lim_{z_\to z_0}\displaystyle\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)-d (z-z_0)}{z-z_0}=0$. 
Obviously, in this case $d=\lim_{z\to z_0}\displaystyle\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}=f'(z_0)$.

Now suppose that $f=u+iv$  is differentiable  at  $z_0=x_0+iy_0$ and its derivative is $d=a+ib$.  Taking $z=x+iy$ and replacing in the limit of the definition above you get that
$u$ and $v$ are differentiable (in real sense) at $(x_0, y_0)$, and satisfy Cauchy-Riemann relations.

Recall that $u$ is differentiable at $(x_0, y_0)$ if there exists $A,B\in\mathbb{R}$, such that
$\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)}\displaystyle\frac{R(x,y)}{\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}}=0$, where
$R(x,y)=u(x,y)-u(x_0,y_0)-A(x-x_0)-B(y-y_0)$. If this is the case we have:
$A=\displaystyle\frac{\partial u(x_0,y_0)}{\partial x},\:B=\displaystyle\frac{\partial u(x_0,y_0)}{\partial y}$.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you xecafe.